# How to Create a customized Directory using java

Tags: java, directory

Problem:
I wanted to create a directory such that when I click on a button for one time the directory must be created with the name "Node_1". when I click on the same button once again the directory must be created with the name "Node_2".

Please do not bother about the button. I need the code where the count must be incremented as stated above.

The below sample code will create a directory with the name "Node_1" When I click once.

But when I click button Once again, it will create a directory with the same name "Node_1" again. But I wanted to create with the name "Node_2".

`String src = "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\src\\Nodes\\Node_1\\n1_sample.txt";`

Comment: Make a counter variable and increment it every time a directory is created.

Comment: *"The below sample code"* What sample code is that? I'm failing to see any code in that question text.

Comment: how can I insert the incremented value in the path?

Comment: *"how can I insert the incremented value"* Using string concatenation: `"foo" + counter + "bar"`

Comment: @Andreas Just check it now!!

Comment: Use a variable for click counter and update the directory string accordingly.

Comment: *"The below sample code will create a directory"* I'm failing to see any code that will create any directory.

Comment: @Andreas I already updated the question

Comment: You added `String src =`. That is not code to *create* a directory. That is just code to assign a string literal to a variable. It barely even categorizes as "sample code".

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I'll put the question in a better way next time. BTW I got the answer what I wanted. Thank you for sparing your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, this will help:

```
int clickCounter = 0;
void onClick() {
    ++clickCounter;
    .
    .
    String src = "...\\Node_" + clickCounter + "\\...txt"
}
```

Note: Learn to ask question in a better way. Share what you want to achieve, what you've tried already, and what problem you are facing, and also keep it simple.

Comment: Also, learn to accept the answer if it solved your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow community.

Comment: My reputation is not greater than 15, That's the reason My acceptance is not counted. It is taken as feedback.